# Create all possible combinations of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, permutation

does anybody know how can I find out all the possible combinations of a given list using Python 3?

My lists look like this:

```
usersArray = ["John", "Mike", "Robert", "Tom"]
foodsArray = ["hamburger", "cake", "cheese"]
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
Johnhamburger
Mikehamburger
Roberthamburger
Tomhamburger

Johncake
Mikecake
Robertcake
Tomcake

Johncheese
Mikecheese
Robertcheese
Tomcheese

#and then the opposite

hamburgerJohn
hamburgerMike
hamburgerRobert
hamburgerTom

cakeJohn
...
...
...

cheeseJohn
...
...
...
```

Can I use `itertools`?
Thank you!

Comment: Show us what you have tried yourself so far.

Comment: No @IrmendeJong

Comment: Excuse me? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

That's just two uses of `itertools` product:

```
for food, user in itertools.product(foodsArray, usersArray):
    print(user+food)

for food, user in itertools.product(foodsArray, usersArray):
    print(food+user)
```

Answer (score 1):

**A pure `Python` solution:**

You can do this with `nested` `for-loops` in a `list-comprehension` and `string` `concatenation`:

```
[u + f for u in usersArray for f in foodsArray]
```

which gives:

```
['Johnhamburger', 'Johncake', 'Johncheese', 'Mikehamburger', 'Mikecake', 'Mikecheese', 'Roberthamburger', 'Robertcake', 'Robertcheese', 'Tomhamburger', 'Tomcake', 'Tomcheese']
```

---

```
[f + u for u in usersArray for f in foodsArray]
```

which gives:

```
['hamburgerJohn', 'cakeJohn', 'cheeseJohn', 'hamburgerMike', 'cakeMike', 'cheeseMike', 'hamburgerRobert', 'cakeRobert', 'cheeseRobert', 'hamburgerTom', 'cakeTom', 'cheeseTom']
```